# How to convert String to date object[without time]

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I have a string which contains a date in YYYYMMDD format (e.g. 20130614), i want to convert it to date and print it like: 'Day Month Day Year' (e.g Fri Jun 14 2013).
I tried to do this with SimpleDateFormat but it returns date and time(i don't want time)
(e.g.  Fri Jun 14 00:00:00 EET 2013).

My code is:

```
String tmpValue = "20130614";
Date date = (Date) new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd").parse(tmpValue);
```

Also, i want after print to convert it back to String with YYYYMMDD format. Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Date` class represents a date *and* time (it's confusingly named) so you'll get a time component regardless. The standard recommendation for a useable and intuitive date/time API is to use [Joda](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/), which gives you these specific models.

To answer your second question, you can convert that back to a string using `SimpleDateFormat` again (check the doc). As before, I would recommend Joda here since the `SimpleDateFormat` class is (counter-intuitively) not thread-safe!

Comment: +1 for JodaTime. By the way, the Joda class you need here would be `LocalDate`.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");  
Date data = new Date(format.parse(tmpValue).getTime());
```